# How to use generic method param in an interface?

Tags: java, generics

I defined a simple base interface, holding one method with a abstract class as parameter.

```
public interface IVisitor {
    void visit(BaseVehicle vehicle);
}
```

This base interface can be extended by another interface, which should be able to overload this method from the base interface several times with more specific classes.

```
public interface ISpecificVisitor extends IVisitor {
    void visit(TruckCar car);
    void visit(Lory car);
}
```

Can one write the base interface with generics so that the sub interface can/must overload with a more specific class? If yes, how would that look like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
public interface IVisitor<T extends BaseVehicle> {
    void visit(T vehicle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, but because of type erasure, you cannot do it in an elegant way:

```
public interface Vehicle {}

public class Car implements Vehicle {}

public class Boat implements Vehicle {}

public interface IVisitor<C extends Vehicle, B extends Vehicle> {
    // These methods have the same erasure, compile time error.
    // void visit(C vehicle);
    // void visit(B vehicle);

    // ugly workaround.
    void visitC(C vehicle);
    void visitB(B vehicle);
}

public class SpecificVisitor implements IVisitor<Car, Boat> {
    @Override
    public void visitC(Car vehicle) {}

    @Override
    public void visitB(Boat vehicle) {}
}
```